# c# console syntax similar to the |more command

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

I am getting data from an API and displaying it to the console using:

`Console.WriteLine("\n" + currentTopic.desc.ToString());`

There is a lot of data. It takes more than the entire console to display. I'd like it to pause at the full console for the user to press a key to continue (simliar to the |more function in the Windows command line). Is this possible?

Thanks!

I have tried to add |more to my Writeline statement:

`Console.WriteLine("\n" + currentTopic.desc.ToString()|more);`

`Console.WriteLine(more < "\n" + currentTopic.desc.ToString());`

`Console.WriteLine("\n" + currentTopic.desc.ToString() + "|more");`

but that does not work.

I have searched both Google and Stack Overflow and have not found an answer.

Comment: Do you want to add the paging behavior to your app (look at the properties of the `Console` class and both `Console.ReadKey` and `Console.ReadLine`). If you want to start up up `more` and pipe your output to that process, look up `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` and `StartInfo`. Sorry, but what you've been trying isn't close at all

Comment: `more` is a program that takes input from stdin and writes that output to a console, pausing for keypress after each page of text. `Console.WriteLine` simply writes the text you pass to it into stdout without intepretating the content. If you want to implement paging then you'll have to write it into your program, `Console.WriteLine` isn't going to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I'll look into these.